# OCR from PDF in Google AppScript not working correctly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, ocr

I have a strange problem with the OCR feature in AppScrip. I use a function to extract text from a PDF. It is used in an automated process to handle PDFs coming from a client. This is the function:

```
function extractTextFromPDF_v1(file) 
{
  var blob = file.getBlob(); 
  var resource = 
  {
    title: blob.getName(),
    mimeType: blob.getContentType()
  }

  var file = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob, {ocr: true, ocrLanguage: "en"});
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.id);
  var text = doc.getBody().getText();

  Drive.Files.trash(file.id);

  return text
}
```

This has been working correctly for the last couple of years, not giving a single problem.

Since a couple of weeks ago I am experiencing problems with this function, having changed nothing. It is used by two different users, and in one of them it was not working correctly. The text appeared in vertical lines, in a strange order. When I get the text back from the function it is unusable.

Strangely, it only happened with this second user, the first one worked correctly. I even created a third user in order to check if it happened too in this third user, but it worked correctly and I got a correct return. So I though it was a punctual problem with Google servers and I went on working, changing the automated process to the third user, temporarilly.

Unfortunatelly, since yesterday I haver the same problem with all three users: I get a bad order text response, which is useless.

I tried to use a new way to do the OCR, and created this second function:

```
function extractTextFromPDF_v2(file) 
{
  var fileId = Drive.Files.insert({title: file.getName(), mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS}, 
  file.getBlob()).id;
  var rt = DocumentApp.openById(fileId);
  var text = rt.getBody().getText();

  Drive.Files.trash(fileId);  

  return text
}
```

But it returns exactly the same answer.

Any help would be heavyly appreciated. We will have to process all PDFs files manually, and there are hundreds every month (!)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you provide tell if this happens for a particular PDF file or for all of them?

Comment: Only with those files coming from my client. Other files ok. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you get the blob from the file `file.getBlob()` explicitly as a PDF? Try getting it explicitly [`file.getAs('application/pdf')`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getascontenttype)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this way :

```
            var blob = PDF_file.copyBlob();
            var file = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
            var id = Drive.Files.insert({title: "tmp_doc", mimeType:MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS}, file.getBlob()).id;
            var rt = DocumentApp.openById(id);
            var txt = rt.getBody().getText();
            Drive.Files.remove(id);
            file.setTrashed(true);
```